# Woocommerce empty cart and add a new product on specific page template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to empty the cart before adding a new product and it works with this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'wdm_empty_cart', 10,  3);

function wdm_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Now I need to do this on a specific page template. Is that possible?

I tried this but it's not working

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'wdm_empty_cart', 10,  3);

function wdm_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    if (is_page_template('templates/checkout.php')){
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
    
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/ ?

Comment: Yes, I did but I'm not familiar with PHP so I must be doing something wrong because it's not working.

Comment: @NikolaSoro for clarity, do you mean with _"on specific page template"_ - the single product page, shop page, page with id..  where you actually mean [WooCommerce conditional tags](https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) + [WordPress conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) or the specific template filename for a given post

Comment: I have multiple checkout pages(The developer who previously worked on this website created them) I created my own checkout page and added it as my default checkout page in woocommerce. This checkout page is using a custom template called checkout.php and it's in subfolder templates templates/checkout.php